# Updated app.config Still getting WCF Quota Message Size Error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, binding

I have updated my App.config as below:

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <!--<service name="NorthWindService" />-->
      <service name="DBConnector.DataRetriever" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="/NorthWind/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="/NorthWind" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_NorthWind"
          name="NorthWindEndPoint" contract="DBConnector.IDataRetrieve" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Services/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
     <bindings>

    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_NorthWind" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But still getting the error while invoking from WCFTestClient.

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages 
>   (65536) has been exceeded.
>
> To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

What am I missing?

Comment: What config do you have on your client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not show any config for your client, so I'm just throwing this out.

You need to also set the maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" attribute in the .config of the client.

Somewhere along these lines (some attributes from binding where omitted for brewity:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_NorthWind" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2097152" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint 
              address="http://somesite.com/endpoint.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_NorthWind"
              contract="IYourServiceContract" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Remove the readerQuotas element if you don't need it.

EDIT: updated with client element.

Comment: Not Sure about Config of Client , do you mean the configuration inside the <client> section?

Comment: A client has an endpoint, and in that endpoint you specify address, binding, bindingConfiguration and contract. The sample above uses a basicHttpBinding, with the bame BasicHttpBinding_NorthWind. You should have something similar in the project where you added the service reference.

Comment: Can I do something when using with WCFTEstClient?

Comment: When You Test the application with WCF Test Client , then a Client.config get generated automatically with default values. Is there a way to edit them?

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the autogenerated config from wcftest. When I test my services I usually create a console project. That way I can inspect the config, and test every method with mock up data if I want to. In wcftest you would have to supply data each time as far as I know.